# Baking fluid at high resolution doesn't appear

Tags: fluid-simulation

So I'm trying to simulate fluid. When baking at 75res, everything shows up fine:
[image]
However, when I bake at 300res, nothing ever shows up:
[image]

EDIT: The max. resolution that will actually display is 242.

EDIT 2: The problem solved itself. Don't know what I did, but I gave it a day and it displayed. I'll leave this question open if anyone knows why this happened.

Comment: So now that you know the max res is 242, is there still a question? Or do you want to post that as an answer and say "case closed"?

Comment: @Mentalist I still want a higher resolution. It's still a problem. What I meant by the edit is the maximum resolution I can bake fluid at and it still displays in 242. I would like a resolution of 300 or higher

Comment: upload the .blend? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I looked at what the [Blender Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/fluid/baking.html) has to say about baking fluid sims, and while I didn't see any mention of an inherent resolution limit, I did notice there is a display for the amount of Required Memory. Just curious, does the value you see shown exceed your machine's limitations?

Comment: @Mentalist I have 8gigs, and wasn't running anything else. The bake required 2.42

Comment: Also, I noticed the resolution of 75 you refer to is (based on your screen shot) the Final resolution, not the Preview resolution. It is important to distinguish between the two. And changing the Final resolution value should not affect how the fluid is displayed in the Viewport, as this is (supposed to be) determined by the Preview resolution. If changing the Final resolution is having an effect on how the fluid is displayed *in the Viewport*, maybe you should file a bug report. BTW, what version of Blender are you using?

Comment: @Mentalist Under the Preview resolution, you can see that I have my View port Display set to Final, meaning no matter what the preview resolution is, it will display the final resolution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I really wish that setting the Viewport Display to Final would cause the Preview input field to gray out, because then we probably wouldn't even be discussing these semantics. But yeah, usability, human interface, blah blah blah... it can always be improved.